# In Linux, Is there anyway to reserving memory that will be commit automatically when each page got accessed?

Tags: c, linux, posix

Let say I want to allocate 2 MB contiguous memory in a reserved state. Then when the page get accessed in the first time it will be automatically commit only that page. Is there any API to do this without manual commit whenever it raise a page fault?

Comment: malloc practically just does this

Comment: What, exactly you mean by *commit*, here? Typically, *commit* is used in reference to some backing storage. In Linux, on architectures that support virtual memory, memory allocation only prepares the virtual memory for the userspace process to use; it does not actually commit them to physical RAM. That occurs on the first access (and on first write access for memory marked copy-on-write). If you are referring to memory-mapped files or devices, and having to call `msync()` after writes to ensure the mapping and the backing store are in sync, then at least I am not aware of such an API.

Comment: Thank you guys! That is what I want. What I want to do is allocate stack for my co-routine and commit only the pages that currently use. That mean I can allocate virtual address in a big size first and slowly commit only pages that need to use.